# What are the elements of the modular ring mod 7?

Tags: cryptography, modular-arithmetic

Are the elements of a modular ring simply the set of all the numbers from 1 to p−1?

in this case p−1 = 6 ?

I asked this on the math stack exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3375667 and was told that 0 is included in the the ring. Is this treated differently in CS ?

Comment: Your question is answered completely on [math.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confusing the ring and the multiplicative group of invertible elements mod p.
The first one is isomorphic to the integers from 0 to p-1, 0 being the additive neutral element, and 1 being the multiplicative neutral element.

If p is prime, the intervible elements are the integers from 1 to p-1, and they form a multiplicative group.

By the way, when p is prime, such a ring (all elements except 0 are invertible) is called a field.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't treated any different.

The elements in the mod ring of any integer x include all numbers in the range `[0,x-1]`.

However, different programming languages treat negative numbers in different ways.

`(-5) MOD 3 = 1` in Python.

whereas,

`(-5) MOD 3 = -2` in C.

This problem can be solved by simply adding the value to the negative result.

In this case `-2 + 3 results in 1`.